# How to enable ZoomControls in android WebView when open specific URL?

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I'm using WebView in android; I want to show ZoomControls not for all pages but only for my specific webpage. What should I do? Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that it's an activity and you are receiving the url from the intent

```
String url = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_id_here)

webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(url.equals("your_url_here"));
```

If you want this to happen every time a url changes, use a custom webview client.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
```

wherever the webView is initialized. CustomWebViewClient :

```
private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        view.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(url.equals("your_url_here"));
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: will this code execute setting of zoom control after each request or does he need to set some listener too?